# Updating element of vector via pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

In one of my larger projects I came across an issue w/ updating elements of a vector via pointers. I've created a simpler demonstration of my problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

const int LOOKUP = 3;

struct Box {
    int use;
    int cap;
};

void print_vec(std::vector<Box>* bx) {
    for ( Box &b : *bx ) { 
        std::cout << "Box: " << b.use << "/" << b.cap << std::endl;
    }; 
}

void find_box(std::vector<Box>* bx, Box** bptr) {
    for ( Box &b : *bx) {
        if (b.use == LOOKUP) {
            *bptr = &b;
            return;
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    std::vector<Box> boxes = { {1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3}, {4,4}, {5,5} };
    std::vector<Box>* bx = &boxes;

    Box** bptr = new Box *;
    Box b;

    print_vec(bx);

    find_box(bx, bptr);

    b = **bptr;

    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Found box w size: " << b.use << std::endl;
    b.cap = 99;
    std::cout << "New capacity: " << b.cap << std::endl << std::endl;

    print_vec(bx);
}
```

Output:

```
Box: 1/1
Box: 2/2
Box: 3/3
Box: 4/4
Box: 5/5

Found box w size: 3
New capacity: 99

Box: 1/1
Box: 2/2
Box: 3/3
Box: 4/4
Box: 5/5
```

My assumption would be that the third box, after updating would read 3/99...
Is my pointer-to-pointer pointing to a copy of the vector's element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With

```
Box b;
b = **bptr;
```

You do a copy into `b`.

with reference(/pointer), you will modify element from vector.

```
Box& b = **bptr;
b.cap = 99;
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/0EfOzu)